# Java MySQL PreparedStatement.setBoolean wraps value in quotes

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

#### Short version of my question is:

```
PreparedStatement ps;
ps = connection.prepareStatement("Insert into T values (?)");
ps.setBoolean(1, true);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

What can be the reasons for this code sample to produce query with value wrapped in quotes?

#### Long version of my question is:

I have JavaEE application with plain JDBC for DB interactions and recently I noticed that there are some `MySQLDataTruncation` exceptions appearing in my logs. These exceptions were occurring on attempt to save entity into DB table which have boolean column defined as `BIT(1)`. And it was because generated query looked like this:

```
Insert into T values ('1');
```

Note that value is wrapped with quotes. Query was logged from application with Log4J `log.info(ps);` statement.
Previous logs demonstrate that there where no quotes.

Furthermore, even MySQL server logs started to look different. Before this happened I had given pairs of records for each query executed:

```
12345 Prepare Insert into T values (?)
12345 Execute Insert into T values (1)
```

And after:

```
12345 Query Insert into T values ('1')
```

It is worth noting that those changes wasn`t a result of deploying new version of application or even restarting MySQL/Application server and code, responsible of query generation, is as straightforward as example in this question.

Application server restart fixed the issue for about 12 hours, and then it happened again. As a temporary solution I changed `BIT` columns to `TINYINT`

P.S. Examining both aplication and MySQL logs allowed to narrow down the time span when something went wrong to about 2 minutes, but there were nothing abnormal in the logs in this period.

P.P.S. Application server is Glassfish 2.1.1, MySQL server version is 5.5.31-1~dotdeb and MySQL Connector/J version is 5.0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out it was actually an issue with unclosed prepared statements.
When opened statements count at MySQL server reached its allowed maximum, application was still able to continue working somehow, withoout producing sql error:

```
Error Code: 1461 Can’t create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements
```

But in that *mode* it started to wrap boolean values with quotes, causing all my troubles affecting BIT(1) columns.